# why $f(x)=0$ on $K_2?$

Tags: measure-theory

I have some   confusion in Rudin Book

Theorem  $2.14 $ : The  Reisz Representation theorem

My confusion is given below    marked in red  box

[image]

**My confusion** : why   $f(x)=0$ on $K_2?$

**My thinking** : By using  urysohn's lemma  we have $ K_2 \prec  f \prec  V$ for  some  $f \in  C_c(X) $.

This  implies   $f(x)=1$ on $ K_2$

Comment: Please [replace the image of text by actual text](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question#10992) with formulas typed using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). Images can't be searched using search engines and aren't accessible for users with screen readers etc.

Comment: next  time  i will  try to use  MathJax  @Christoph

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just look up what [Urysohn's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Urysohn%27s_lemma) actually states:

> A topological space $X$ is [normal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_space) if and only if, for any two non-empty closed disjoint subsets $A$ and $B$ of $X$, there exists a continuous map $f\colon X\to [0,1]$ such that $f(a)=0$ for all $a\in A$ and $f(b)=1$ for all $b\in B$.

In your case $A=K_2$ and $B=K_1$.